# Python: parse xml to dictionary and filter only specific fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Using: Python3

Hi, Please help me on below challenge.

i am able to parse a XML file and put the data into dictionary format.. but i want to merge the dictionaries based on starting parameter of each dictionary (RecordType) and filter specific parameters from them..

my `dummy2.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<records>
<record source="AS/SCP" type="call">
<group name="General">
<field name="RecordType" value="HEC"/>
<field name="RecordTypeHEC" value="AO"/>
<field name="NodeID" value="example.111"/>
<field name="SequenceNumber" value="311496"/>
<field name="StartDate" value="20181009042152033"/>
<field name="EndDate" value="20181009042152033"/>
<field name="CallDuration" value="0"/>
<field name="CauseForRecordClosing" value="normal"/>
</group>
<group name="SIP">
<field name="ICID" value="dsds"/>
<field name="CallID" value="dsyids@10.10.10.9"/>
<field name="User-Agent" value="Cisco-CUCM10.5"/>
<field name="Request-URI" value="sip:+792642"/>
<field name="CalledPartyNumber" value="sip:+237937193"/>
<field name="CallingPartyNumber" value="sip:+94362863185@dsjolj.example.com"/>
<field name="To" value="sip:+8777447585984834@10.10.10.1:5060"/>
<field name="From" value="sip:+941344903000@11.11.11.1:5060"/>
<field name="RedirectingPartyNumber" value="sip:+3296321931@dsjolj.example.com"/>
</group>
<group name="VPN">
<field name="VPN_NAME_A" value="NEW"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_A" value="NEW91"/>
<field name="A_ExtType" value="pstn"/>
<field name="A_ISDN" value="+3296321931"/>
<field name="A_SIP" value="sip:+3296321931@dsjolj.example.com"/>
<field name="VPN_NAME_B" value="NEW"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_B" value="NEW91"/>
<field name="B_ExtType" value="mobile"/>
<field name="B_IMSI" value="447732636286"/>
<field name="B_MSISDN" value="+9483268631"/>
<field name="VPN_CallType" value="onnet"/>
<field name="A_PABXID" value="93972"/>
<field name="B_PABXID" value="86328"/>
</group>
</record>
<record source="AS/SCP" type="call">
<group name="General">
<field name="RecordType" value="HEC"/>
<field name="RecordTypeHEC" value="AO"/>
<field name="NodeID" value="example.111"/>
<field name="SequenceNumber" value="83728"/>
<field name="StartDate" value="20181009042152355"/>
<field name="EndDate" value="20181009042152355"/>
<field name="CallDuration" value="0"/>
<field name="CauseForRecordClosing" value="480"/>
</group>
<group name="SIP">
<field name="ICID" value="863286382"/>
<field name="CallID" value="832683628@10.10.10.9"/>
<field name="User-Agent" value="NotPresent"/>
<field name="Request-URI" value="sip:+792642"/>
<field name="CalledPartyNumber" value="sip:+237937193"/>
<field name="CallingPartyNumber" value="sip:+94362863185@dsjolj.example.com"/>
<field name="To" value="sip:+8777447585984834@dsjolj.example.com:5060"/>
<field name="From" value="sip:+941344903000@10.10.10.1:5060"/>
<field name="RedirectingPartyNumber" value="sip:+3296321931@dsjolj.example.com"/>
</group>
<group name="VPN">
<field name="VPN_NAME_A" value="NEW"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_A" value="NEW91"/>
<field name="A_ExtType" value="pstn"/>
<field name="A_ISDN" value="+3296321931"/>
<field name="A_SIP" value="sip:+3296321931@dsjolj.example.com"/>
<field name="VPN_NAME_B" value="NEW"/>
<field name="VPN_Group_B" value="NEW91"/>
<field name="B_ExtType" value="mobile"/>
<field name="B_IMSI" value="4486328632"/>
<field name="B_MSISDN" value="+948362862"/>
<field name="VPN_CallType" value="onnet"/>
<field name="A_PABXID" value="438632"/>
<field name="B_PABXID" value="326836"/>
</group>
</record>
</records>
```

I have below python code to parse above XML:

```
import sys
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree

def creat_group_dict(group_object):
    group_dict = {}
    for field in group_object.findall('./field'):
        group_dict[field.attrib['name']] = field.attrib['value']        
    return group_dict

def parse_xml():
    result_list = []
    tree = ElementTree()
    tree.parse("dummy.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()    
    groups = root.findall('.//group')
    for data in groups:
      sampl = creat_group_dict(data)
      result_list.append(sampl)
    return result_list

parse_xml()
```

output:

```
[{'RecordType': 'RESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'PY', 'NodeID': 'rock.dsjjgds.cm', 'SequenceNumber': '7937973', 'StartDate': '20171049979', 'EndDate': '201704059739793', 'CallDuration': '973979i', 'CauseForRecordClosing': 'normal'}, {'ICID': 'dshhkdhs', 'CallID': 'sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1', 'User-Agent': 'NotPresent', 'Request-URI': 'sip:+47668384', 'CalledPartyNumber': 'sip:+08779379972', 'CallingPartyNumber': 'sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1', 'To': 'sip:+878379739', 'From': 'sip:+937973962'}, {'VPN_NAME_B': 'blshahd', 'VPN_Group_B': 'ctr', 'A_ExtType': 'part', 'A_ISDN': '7973', 'A_SIP': '67367672', 'A_PABXID': '797397'}, {'RecordType': 'MESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'DY', 'NodeID': 'rock.dsjjgds.cm', 'SequenceNumber': '7937973', 'StartDate': '20171049979', 'EndDate': '201704059739793', 'CallDuration': '973979i', 'CauseForRecordClosing': 'normal'}, {'ICID': 'dshhkdhs', 'CallID': 'sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1', 'User-Agent': 'NotPresent', 'Request-URI': 'sip:+47668384', 'CalledPartyNumber': 'sip:+08779379972', 'CallingPartyNumber': 'sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1', 'To': 'sip:+878379739', 'From': 'sip:+937973962'}, {'VPN_NAME_B': 'blshahd', 'VPN_Group_B': 'ctr', 'B_ExtType': 'part', 'B_ISDN': '7973', 'B_SIP': '67367672', 'B_PABXID': '797397'}]
```

I want to merge the dictionaries based on their starting field `RecordType`

Required Output:

```
{'RecordType': 'RESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'PY', 'NodeID': 'rock.dsjjgds.cm', 'SequenceNumber': '7937973', 'StartDate': '20171049979', 'EndDate': '201704059739793', 'CallDuration': '973979i', 'CauseForRecordClosing': 'normal', 'ICID': 'dshhkdhs', 'CallID': 'sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1', 'User-Agent': 'NotPresent', 'Request-URI': 'sip:+47668384', 'CalledPartyNumber': 'sip:+08779379972', 'CallingPartyNumber': 'sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1', 'To': 'sip:+878379739', 'From': 'sip:+937973962', 'VPN_NAME_B': 'blshahd', 'VPN_Group_B': 'ctr', 'A_ExtType': 'part', 'A_ISDN': '7973', 'A_SIP': '67367672', 'A_PABXID': '797397'}

{'RecordType': 'MESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'DY', 'NodeID': 'rock.dsjjgds.cm', 'SequenceNumber': '7937973', 'StartDate': '20171049979', 'EndDate': '201704059739793', 'CallDuration': '973979i', 'CauseForRecordClosing': 'normal', 'ICID': 'dshhkdhs', 'CallID': 'sdidydakyd2133@10.10.10.1', 'User-Agent': 'NotPresent', 'Request-URI': 'sip:+47668384', 'CalledPartyNumber': 'sip:+08779379972', 'CallingPartyNumber': 'sip:+07073873772@10.0.0.1', 'To': 'sip:+878379739', 'From': 'sip:+937973962', 'VPN_NAME_B': 'blshahd', 'VPN_Group_B': 'ctr', 'B_ExtType': 'part', 'B_ISDN': '7973', 'B_SIP': '67367672', 'B_PABXID': '797397'}
```

and also filter with only required parameter(print if they are available)

```
filter: {RecordType, RecordTypeHEC, A_ISDN, B_ISDN, A_SIP, B_SIP}
```

Required Output after filter:

```
{'RecordType': 'RESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'PY', 'A_ISDN': '7973', 'A_SIP': '67367672'}
{'RecordType': 'MESGJG', 'RecordTypeHEC': 'DY', 'B_ISDN': '7973', 'B_SIP': '67367672'}
```

please help.. i am new to Python..
THANKS IN ADVANCE..

Answer (score 0):

So for grouping use this:

```
def group(output, key):
    grouped_output = {}
    group_by = None
    for record in output:
        # check if still same RecordType
        group_by = record[key] if key in record else group_by
        # merge data for same RecordType
        grouped_by_key = grouped_output.get(group_by, {})
        grouped_output[group_by] = {**grouped_by_key, **record}

    # turn it into a list
    return [record for _, record in grouped_output.items()]
```

Like this:

```
output = parse_xml()
grouped_output = group(output, 'RecordType')
```

Then just filter it:

```
filter_fields = [
  'RecordType', 'RecordTypeHEC', 'A_ISDN', 'B_ISDN', 'A_SIP', 'B_SIP'
]
filtered_output = [
  {key: value for key, value in record.items() if key in filter_fields} for record in grouped_output
]
```

And print it:

```
for record in filtered_output:
    print(record)
```

Comment: thanks a lot Marcos... for merge operation, my XML has 2 records (data between<record> to </record>) and each record starts with 'RecordType'.. and i want to split  lines of XML based on records.. currently python splits them to dict based on 'groups'

Comment: present output: [{RecordType:blabla, .....}, {.......}. {......}, {RecordType:next}, {.....}, {......}]

Comment: required OP: {RecordType:blabla...,....,....,....,.....}, {RecordType:next,....,.....,.....,......}

Comment: Hi Marcos.. thanks again,, it works with dummy.xml and when i apply this with my actual xml file, i am getting only last record, and its happening at grouped_output = group(output, 'RecordType') and no issue with filtering.. i dont understand whats the problem, because both my xml's are similar.

Comment: i have updated question, at previous xml with other XML, with which i am only getting last record.